# How can I model a polymorphic, custom name relationship using Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, models, relationships

I'm attempting to define a series of model relationships using custom names for a model in some instances, and it's native name in others. Furthermore, the model can be referenced by multiple classes, necessitating a polymorphic relationship.

The following models are simplified (I've removed fields, additional relationships, etc.), but they exemplify the structure I'm attempting to produce while avoid creating inherited models.

```
class Gallery
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :galleryable, polymorphic: true
end

class App
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one  :about, class_name: 'Gallery', inverse_of: :galleryable
  embeds_one  :portfolio
end

class Portfolio
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :app
  embeds_many :galleries, as: :galleryable
end
```

I understand that the "child" being embedded by a custom relation should also have a `class_name` definition and an `inverse_of:`, but how can I define these values without needing to explicitly define the associated class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to define the association property **":as"** :

```
  class Gallery
    include Mongoid::Document
    embedded_in :galleryable, polymorphic: true
  end

  class App
    include Mongoid::Document
    embeds_one  :about, as: :galleryable
    embeds_one  :portfolio
  end

  class Portfolio
    include Mongoid::Document
    embedded_in :app
    embeds_many :galleries, as: :galleryable
  end
```

Hope it helps!